# Speed of car pulling a rope

Tags: derivatives

A car is being pulled along by a rope attached to the tow-bar at the back of the car.
The rope passes through a pulley, the top of which is $3$ metres further from the ground than the tow-bar.
The pulley is $x$ metres horizontally from the tow-bar.
The rope is being winched in at a speed of $0.6 \; \text{ms}^{-1}$.
The wheels of the car remain in contact with the ground.

At what speed is the car moving when the length of the rope, $L$, between the tow-bar and the pulley is $5.4$ metres?

I drew a right-angle triangle with the hypotenuse being $L$, adjacent being $x$ and tangent being $3$.

We know that the speed of the rope is $0.6$, i.e. $\frac{dR}{dt} = 0.6$.

Not too sure what to do next by it seems the chain rule is gonna be used somewhere.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You have a reasonable amount of explanatory text, here, but a picture would really set up good understanding.

Comment: $\frac{dR}{dt} = -0.6$ I believe.  The length of the rope is *decreasing.*

Comment: What you have said is correct, except for the sign error I've already pointed out.  You need to solve for $x$ in terms of $R$, which is easy, given your triangle, and then apply the chain rule.  Try that, and come back if it doesn't work out for you.

Comment: Using Pythagoras' Theorem $x = \sqrt{L^2-9}$ so $\frac{dx}{dL} = \frac{L}{\sqrt{L^2-9}}$ so using the chain rule $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dL}\times \frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{-0.6L}{\sqrt{L^2-9}}.$$ Throw in $L = 5.4$ and we are done.